# Printing variable without wrapping tag in Pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I want to print some arbitrary content within  tag. The content should be set from Javascript. Here's a minimal example:

```js
pug.compileFile("templates/question.pug")({
   headExtraContent: "<script>console.log('hello')</script>",
});
```

```
doctype
   head
      title Some page title
      // headExtraContent should go here in an unescaped form
   body
      ...
```

I've tried `#{headExtraContent}`, `={headExtraContent`, none of those worked.

Is there a way to achieve this in Pug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the [unescaped string interpolation syntax](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped) Declan mentions with the [text block in a tag](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html#block-in-a-tag) technique also described in the pug documentation.

In your case, it would look like this:

```
doctype
  head
    title Some page title
    .
      !{headExtraContent}
  body
    ...
```

When in doubt, the [documentation](https://pugjs.org/) will have what you need 99% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Pug.js docs](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html), `!{headExtraContent}` will insert content without escaping.

Comment: Unfortunately, this syntax throws an "unexprected text" error when used without wrapping tag (i.e `!{headExtraContent}` instead of `div !{headExtraContent}`